# Typeorm migration generate

Tags: javascript, typescript, migration, typeorm, nest

So i have modules and there i have entities.
For example i have user module, and in user module there is entities folder, where i can have more than one entitie. src/modules/user/entities/user.entity.ts

So i want to generate migrations with all of this entities, and then i want to run created migrations.

So how i know with typeorm migration:generate, it must generate migrations with help of entities.

This is my typeorm.ts file

```
import { registerAs } from '@nestjs/config';
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
import { config as dotenvConfig } from 'dotenv';

dotenvConfig({ path: '.env' });

export const dbConfig = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: `${process.env.DB_HOST}`,
  port: parseInt(`${process.env.DB_PORT}`),
  username: `${process.env.DB_USER}`,
  password: `${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}`,
  database: `${process.env.DB_NAME}`,
  entities: ['./dist/src/modules/**/entities/*.ts'],
  // On ts file it does not work.
  migrations: ['./dist/src/database/migrations/*.js'],
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  synchronize: false,
  migrationsRun: true,
};

export const typeorm = registerAs('typeorm', () => dbConfig);

export default new DataSource(dbConfig as DataSourceOptions);
```

This is my script

**    "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli",
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- --dataSource=config/typeorm.ts migration:generate ./src/database/migrations",
**

so when i run **npm run migration:generate**

its returns

**> typeorm@0.0.1 typeorm

> ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli --dataSource=config/typeorm.ts migration:generate ./src/database/migrations

No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command**

So i don't understand why it does not work. why it does not generate migrations? Can anyone help me with this issue?